# Nginx, Node, Angular - Subfolder API/URL configuration

Tags: node.js, angularjs, nginx

I currently have a node/angular app that runs as expected when pointed directly to the port configured (8081 for the purposes of explaining my situation).  I'm able to post,get,put,delete as expected.

My goal is to have the node application running at mydomain.com/subfolder.  When nginx is configured with the location of '/', everything works as expected.  Config below:

```
upstream app_yourdomain {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name yourdomain.com yourdomain;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/yourdomain.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://app_yourdomain/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

As soon as I change the location to /subfolder, however, my get,post,put,delete requests return 404 responses.  The index.html configured in the node application is returned though.  Configuration below:

```
upstream app_yourdomain {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name yourdomain.com yourdomain;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/yourdomain.log;

    location /subfolder {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://app_yourdomain/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

In my angular factory, I have my requests structured like  `return $http.get('/subfolder');` or `return $http.post('/subfolder', {data: data});`.

And, within my node application, I have the routes defined like `app.get('/subfolder', somefunction);` or `app.post('/subfolder', somefunction);`

Again, when I have the application running from the root of the domain, it works fine.  When I have it configured to be in a subfolder of the domain, however, the requests no longer work.

My end goal would be to have multiple node applications running from sub-folders of a main domain.  I've been fighting with this for a while, and found several articles for hosting mutliple node apps on a single server, but they seem geared toward having separate domains.  I'd like (if possible) for these to run as separate apps for the same domain.

Any thoughts/tricks/pointers?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Modify Your Nginx File to look like this:

```
 upstream node{
        server  127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

listen 0.0.0.0:80;
server_name yourdomain.com yourdomain;
access_log /var/log/nginx/yourdomain.log;

location /node {
      rewrite /node(.*) $1 break;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://node;
      proxy_redirect http://node/ /node;
}
```

I got the above from here: http://skovalyov.blogspot.com/2012/07/deploy-multiple-node-applications-on.html and it works for me